# Should I use this partitioning/indexing strategy for a table that grows by about a billion rows per year?

Tags: index, mariadb, partitioning, big-data

I'm a software engineer with about 10 years of experience building Laravel web applications for small businesses. I'm pretty comfortable with database design, but it's not my greatest strength.

One of the applications I've built is a third-party tool for monitoring email newsletter opens and clicks. This app stores open and click events, and users of the tool query these events to see how their email newsletters are doing. The current row count for the analytics events table is about 1.5 billion, which is about a year and a half of data.

I plan to migrate to a new database design and would like to see if my understanding of database design is on track.

These are the tables for the new database:
[image]

```
Table contacts {
  id integer
  email_address string
  created_at datetime
  updated_at datetime
  indexes {
    id [pk]
    email_address
    created_at
  }
}

Table contact_opens {
  id unsignedBigInteger
  contact_id integer
  sent_at datetime
  opened_at datetime
  indexes {
    id [pk]
    (contact_id, sent_at)
    sent_at
    opened_at
  }
}

Table contact_clicks {
  id unsignedBigInteger
  contact_id integer
  sent_at datetime
  clicked_at datetime
  indexes {
    id [pk]
    (contact_id, sent_at)
    sent_at
    clicked_at
  }
}
```

I plan to use MariaDB on a dedicated linode server with 64gb of RAM, partition the database on a calendar month basis, and tune InnoDB as follows:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48GB
InnoDB File-Per-Table = ON
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = 0_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size = 8GB
table_open_cache = 20
```

The queries against this database will be segmenting Contacts based on Opens and Clicks. For example:

- Contacts with 5 or more opens in the last 30 days
- Contacts with at least 1 click in the last 5 days
- Contacts with 1 click on each of the last 30 days
- etc., standard email newsletter segmenting queries (as seen on Mailchimp)

The queries will return anywhere from 10k-300k contacts at a time.

I've done a fair amount of research and it appears that indexing, partitioning, and/or sharding appears to be the best option to help speed up the queries. It seems that a combination of indexing and partitioning would be best suited for this particular use case.

**Does this use sound like a sound database design where the opens table grows by about a billion rows per year, and the clicks table grows by about 300 million rows per year?**

**Update 1:**
The schema will not change. It is changing slightly from how it was designed years ago, but only to accomodate the changes outlined in this quesiton to make the queries faster.

**Update 2:**
The 300k~ contact queries are for mass mailings (email newsletters). Updated the data types in the MySQL tables above.

Comment: Is the schema stable or do you expect it to change multiple times over the year?

Comment: If all the queries includes a condition by the date within some last days then partitioning by the date must improve these queries due to partition pruning. Using monthly partitioning will produce partitions ~100kk rows each for opens table and ~25kk rows per clicks. Average query will investigate only 1-2 partitions instead of the whole table.

Comment: From the other side.. indexing and partitioning are independent (with some restrictions), and correct indices will improve the query heavily. So you'd combine these techniques.

Comment: Also - if the most part of your queries retrieves described daily (and more) statistic then you may use pre-calculation. I.e. when a day is completed then you'd retrieve this day statistics and store in separate table. This table will be compact enough (1 row for each kind of the statistic per day). When the user needs in this statistic then you get the data which is already "ready to use", apply additional aggregation and return needed output. And only current day statistic and exotic statistic which is not pre-calculated needs in raw data access in this case.

Comment: @Akina What benefit does partition pruning have instead of a proper index that seeks directly to that subset of the data instead? Would that not be the same thing in regards to the amount of data that is utilized?

Comment: @J.D. Instead of? none. In addition - the size of the index to be loaded/cached. Compare - to read the index for the whole table and those for 1-2 partitions..

Comment: @Akina I can't say specifically for MariaDB, but if it functions like SQL Server, an index seek does not cause the entire index of the whole table to be loaded, only the needed pages of data for that part of the index is. I would imagine MariaDB is smart enough to do the same.

Comment: @J.D. - MySQL/MariaDB (using InnoDB) caches data and index "blocks".  Each is 16KB, containing several dozen rows or index entries.  The cache is organized roughly as least-recently-used.  So, an index lookup will usually find most or all of the needed blocks in RAM.  Partitioning does not substantively change the number of blocks accessed (assuming the optimal indexes are available in either case).

Comment: @RickJames Gotcha, thanks, sounds on par to SQL Server then. It's 8 KB and called pages but same idea. In SQL Server, partitioning on the same key as an index shouldn't result in any less data being loaded from disk - as long as the query elicits index seeks. Sounds like MariaDB is similar in nature.

Comment: @J.D. - I find that Partitioning almost never improves _performance_.  The main use is for "deleting" data older than X days/weeks/months/years.  `DROP PARTITION` and add a new partition for a "time series" is a lot faster than a big delete.  Have you found an app (in SQL Server or others) where `SELECTs` clearly benefit from Partitioning?  ("Partition pruning" is usually no better than a suitable composite index.)

Comment: @RickJames Completely agree to a T. It's a data management tool. Dropping old partitions to clean up data outside the retention window makes sense. Improving `SELECT` performance, nah. I've heard partition pruning claimed as the go-to for improving `SELECT` performance, but I've never seen it improve performance over a proper index. And I can't believe that to be true when an equivalent index gets you index seeks. The only case I can see being made where partitioning *may* improve performance is if a huge table was being scanned and there was no good index to elicit seeks. Then at least the...

Comment: ...scan would be contained to only the partition(s) that matter (I'm assuming) if the query did use partition pruning. But this is so edge case of a scenario, especially in SQL Server which offers multiple solutions for large scan type of queries anyway such as batch mode, columnstore indexing, and index hints to force a seek when the dev knows better than the SQL engine.

Comment: @J.D. - Scan?  A point query with a good index does not "scan".  A `WHERE` that only does partition pruning would scan the entire partition (or an index in the partition); but a non-partitioned `INDEX` can _start with_ the "partition key", thereby scanning a similar number of rows.

Comment: @J.D. - And...  Sure, there are a _few_ rare queries that might benefit from pruning+indexing.  But they are rare.  Here, for example, is a kludgy way to use a "bounding box" to "find nearest -- prune by latitude, then have longitude at start of PK:  [_Find Nearest_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)

Comment: With 1.5 billion rows cut into 36-ish evenly sized partitions by date, wouldn't partition pruning eliminate the number of records to 40-80 million (1 or two partitions being queried for the analytics data) with indexes further speed it up? Or am I wildly misunderstanding?

Comment: @RickJames "*Scan? A point query with a good index does not "scan".*" - Certain types of queries need to analyze a majority of the data, think of OLAP type aggregations that one would normally see in a data warehouse. Those will likely end up scanning most or all of the table. On a billion row table that would suck. But if your partitions divide that table into 10s of millions of rows, it could be more reasonable to scan a single partition. I've never seen this used in practice nor have had anyone mention it as a reason for partitioning, so even such a case is probably rare as there are...

Comment: ...other solutions in most database systems anyway. Perhaps maintaining a data warehouse or minimally summary tables in some database systems are the solution. SQL Server also has some nice features such as batch mode and columnstore indexing to automatically manage the data for you and improve those types of queries.

Comment: @KenSchnetz If you architect your database properly, design your queries efficiently, and put in proper indexes such that you're getting index seeks, then partitioning is just a less efficient data structure dividing up the data than an index. An index is typically stored in a B-Tree which divides up (partitions in a sense) the data logarithmically as opposed to to the partitioning feature which divides the data linearly which is exponentially less efficient. The partitioning feature is not a performance tool, especially with DQL type queries. It's a data management tool.

Comment: @J.D. - Summary tables avoid big scans by keeping summary tables up to date -- either at the time of INSERT or, say, daily.  This allows most OLAP queries to run upwards of 10x faster.  (Note that the OP liked my suggestion of Summary tables.)  Alas, MySQL has no automation for such, or any "materialized views"; so I wrote [_Summary Tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .

Comment: MariaDB has (had?) a Columnstore engine; MySQL does not.  Columnstore main benefit is in 10x compression of the data.

Comment: @RickJames Columnstore gets you great compression for aggregative type queries that typically look up and down a few columns, but also uses batch mode (on SQL Server at least) to process the aggregations which helps speed those type of queries tremendously too. And the best part on SQL Server is you don't have to manage the data yourself like one would with a summary table. It's just another type of index that you can create like any other index, and the engine is automatically managing the structure behind the scenes for you. But yea, I think we're on the same page, at the end of the day...

Comment: ...there's multiple solutions out there for dealing with OLAP type queries and large scans, and partitioning isn't one of them, heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id integer [primary key]       -- This needs to be BIGINT UNSIGNED
contact_id unsignedBigInteger  -- You are hoping for billions of contacts?
```

Summary tables will be your salvation!  For that matter, do you really need the raw data (Fact table)?

1B rows/year = 30/second (plus spikes).  This is easily handled by current computers.  What will be bad is if you do a table scan to produce those reports.

Will you be purging the data after, say, 12 months?  If so, [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) the data.

For my discussion of Data Warehousing optimizations, see [*Data Warehouse*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse%3E).  It leads to a discussion of high-speed ingestion, which you probably will not need, and [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables), which you should definitely study.

When a query returns "300k contacts at a time", is this for a mass mailing?  (I can't think what other use you would need for such a large resultset.)

Buffer_pool = 48G -- Fine.  I assume the disk space is big enough for the data.  You might need 100GB of disk space per year for those tables.  (Or much less if you don't keep the Fact table for long, but do keep the Summary table(s) forever.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will be adding summary tables to this database design.